How do I redirect file writing location for a python package?
I have a package that uses one temporary file, and this file is written and loaded using the package functions. The problem is that I am using this package with Azure Functions, and you are only allowed to write to a special location there. How can I force this package to write to this location? The path is defined inside the package as a global variable:
### foo_package.py ###

path = 'file.json'

def read_file():
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)

def save_file(json_data):
    with open(path, "w") as file:
        json.dump(json_data, file)


def foo_function():
    file = load_file()
    ...
    save_file(json_data)

### my_code.py ###

from foo_package import foo_function

foo_function() # writes to ./, but i need to write to /some/path


would it be possible to write to an in-memory file-like object like an io.StringIO instance?

I mean, since you wrote "temporary file", do you really need an actual file? Wouldn't it fix your problem to just keep the data in RAM?

Why can't you import path and modify it appropriately?

As SIGHUP says, just import foo_package and change that path to whatever you want. foo_package.path = '/my/custom/path'

@Jeyekomon It won't work. Check variable scoping in python.

@MykolaZotko Assigning to path will work. Please show code where you think it will not work

Since path is specified as a relative path of 'file.json', you can change your working directory with os.chdir before calling foo_function, and change the working directory back if needed:
### my_code.py ###
import os
from foo_package import foo_function

cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/some/path')
foo_function()
os.chdir(cwd)


Why would you do that when you can just assign to path

@SIGHUP Because this approach is more reliable. Imagine if this function is used in other modules and within other functions.

@MykolaZotko "more reliable"? Why?

I think you're making this more complicated than it really is.
Let's say we have foomod.py like this:
path = "banana"

def read_file():
    print("Reading", path)

Now in some other script we want foomod.read_file() to operate with a different path.
import foomod

foomod.read_file()
foomod.path = __file__ # assign some other filename/path
foomod.read_file()

Output:
Reading banana
Reading /Users/SIGHUP/Python/Jun21.py



my_package.py

path = "/my/path"

def f():
  print(path)


main.py

from my_package import f
from unittest.mock import patch

f()  # prints '/my/path'

with patch("my_package.path", "foo"):
  f()  # prints 'foo'


I think it's a good approach for testing but not for production.
